# When to free a dll after exporting object

Tags: c++, c, dll, free

i am exporting a function from a dll the following way:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) carsim::ICar* __cdecl createCarPlugin() {
     return new CarPlugin();
}
```

In my main-Program I explicitly load the dll to extract this method. The declaration of the interface ICar is recognized by both - the dll and the main-program:

```
std::shared_ptr<ICar> PluginFactory::loadCarPlugin(const std::string& sCar) {
HINSTANCE oDllHandle = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT(sCar.c_str()));
if (!oDllHandle) {
    throw std::string("Could not LoadLibrary: "+sCar);
}

ICarFactory vFactoryFunc = reinterpret_cast<ICarFactory>(::GetProcAddress(oDllHandle, "createCarPlugin"));
if (!vFactoryFunc) {
    ::FreeLibrary(oDllHandle);
    throw std::string("Could not GetProcAddress: createCarPlugin");
}

std::shared_ptr<ICar> pResult(vFactoryFunc());

//::FreeLibrary(oDllHandle);

return pResult;
}
```

The code is working fine, except one issue: As you see the FreeLibrary function is outcommented. That is because i am not sure, when I have to free the library. The ICar-Object is put into a shared pointer, so it will (hopefully) be destroyed when the program is finished. But when I try to free the library there in the code, the program does not work.

Do I have to free it before the program stops?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If `GetProcAddress` fails, you throw before you call `FreeLibrary`, so `FreeLibrary` will never be called in that case.

Comment: As for when to call `FreeLibrary` otherwise, do it when you no longer need the DLL. However, think about that calling `LoadLibrary`/`FreeLibrary` for each and every function call from the DLL adds some overhead, if you need to call multiple functions you might want to load the DLL once early in the program, and unload it once you're certain you won't call any more functions in the DLL.

Comment: @joachim thanks, just fixed it :)

Comment: @joachim there is just one method in my library to export the ICar-Object. I do not really need the dll after exporting the object, I just need to use the object itself

Comment: Then it's fine to call `FreeLibrary` there.

Comment: Does `ICar` have a `Release` method? If yes you should probably be calling it instead of deleting with operator delete i.e. `std::shared_ptr` _(even though, the virtual destructor right inside the library might get directly called to free the memory and call the destructor, you shouldn't rely on it)_. This because the heap of the dll and your app might be different things.

Comment: @thelink2012 why would I call a release method if i can cleanup in the destructor =?

Comment: @kylecorver Your **interface** destructor should be the `Release` method, so it goes the dll code that might have a different heap than yours. If you free something that's not your concern (not related to your heap), well, you are not freeing anything.

Comment: @thelink2012 sorry i still don't really get what you are trying to say :O You mean i should not call the delete method inside my main program, but in the dll? Because the heap of both are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DLL needs to stay loaded for as long  as you're using it, and that includes using the `ICar` instance.  If you free the library and then call a function on that `ICar`, the function might no longer be there - you've freed it.

Saying "I do not really need the dll after exporting the object" is not true - the DLL is where the code of that object lives.

If you want the DLL to remain loaded for the lifetime of your program, then there's no need to explicitly free it - it will be tidied up automatically when the process exits.

Comment: Okay so i can let my code like it is - without FreeLibrary() - and it will work just find? :O Nice :D ty